# Is there a way to have ActionError in Struts 2 with key and values to replace the replacement parameters in properties file with an exception message?

Tags: java, replace, parameters, properties, struts2

I've noticed that *Action Error does not work the same way in **Struts 2** as it works in **Struts 1***.

*In Struts 1 the ActionError constructor takes a key and values as parameters to replace the replacement parameters in the properties file*. I'm trying to achieve the same using the Struts 2 framework (**Struts 2.5.26**). But I'm only able to add ActionErrors using the **addActionError()** method that just takes the message string. I would like to know if there's a way of achieving the same functionality as Struts 1.

The application that I'm working on requires to have message keys with replacement parameters in the properties file and have values as messages caught from the exceptions in the Action Class replacing the replacement parameters.

**Please have a look at the below example for a better understanding.**

For example:

Let us say the global.properties file has this kind of a message key

```
name.error.param = Error caused due to: {0}
```

To replace the above replacement parameters in ActionErrors, **In Struts 1 it would be done as:**

```
new ActionError("name.error.param", e.getMessage());
```

Where “**name.error.param**” is the message key from the properties file. And **e** is an exception message caught in the Action class.

*So the exception message will replace the replacement parameters in “name.error.param”.*

**How can I achieve this in Struts 2?**

Comment: I haven't used Struts 2 in a while but don't the actions have `getText()` methods that allow you to pass the key and the parameter? It would then be something like `addActionError(getText("name.error.param", e.getMessage())`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me but the exception message has to be passed as an Array of Strings. Otherwise it takes the exception message as the default value to be used when a key is not found.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I always think of the `String.format(...)` way of doing it but Struts' `getText()` has a different syntax.

Comment: Oh okay yeah :)